# Value of cell in named table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

How can I get the value of a specific cell in a named table using a readable  formula (i.e. a formula where rows/cells are referenced by name rather than index)?

[image]

In the above picture I want to display the value of the cell `(Income, Feb)` of table `Financials`. What syntax can I use?

Comment: Hi Johan, would an Index Match formula be suitable something along the lines of `=INDEX(Table1,Match("Income",Table1[Financials],0),MATCH("Feb",Table1[#Headers],0),)`  https://exceljet.net/formula/two-way-lookup-with-index-and-match

Comment: @maxhob17 if that's the most readable formula using names I think we must relax that desire

Comment: I don't know of a better way; I suppose you could hide the complexity of that formula by creating a User Defined Function with VBA http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/user-defined-function.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned you could hide the complexity with a user defined function such as

```
Public Function Financials(month As String, item As String) As String

'Object to represent the table    
Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = Range("Table1").ListObject

'Integers to act as coordinates    
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer

'Find the column
x = lo.HeaderRowRange.Find(month).Column - lo.HeaderRowRange.Column + 1

'Find the row
y = lo.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Find(item).Row - lo.HeaderRowRange.Row

' Return the value at the coordinates x,y
Financials = lo.DataBodyRange(y, x).Value

End Function
```

*(Update `Range("Table1").ListObject` with the name of the table in your workbook, alternatively you could add another parameter to the function)*

You would then call this function in a workbook cell such as this example

```
=Financials("Feb", "Profit")
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to believe that Microsoft has not gone all the way to provide a solution to its customers!

Taking the cue from @maxhob17, here is a generalized solution that will work with *any* named table:

```
Public Function TLookup(tablename As String, key As String, col As String)
    'From a table, find the corresponding value for a key (in the first column)

    'Object to represent the table
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = range(tablename).ListObject

    'Integers to act as coordinates
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer

    'Find the column
    x = lo.HeaderRowRange.Find(col).column - lo.HeaderRowRange.column + 1

    'Use the key to find the row
    y = lo.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Find(key).Row - lo.HeaderRowRange.Row

    ' Return the value at the coordinates x,y
    TLookup = lo.DataBodyRange(y, x).Value

End Function
```

> In the VB Window, insert the code above in a module. Remember to save your Excel file in xlsm format.

Then you should be able to insert the following formula in the your table:

```
=TLookup("Financials", "Feb", "Profit")
```

**This trick will change my life; and it might change yours.** It cannot be simpler, can it?

[I also documented this solution in github](https://gist.github.com/fralau/e4e0810130bf9cc342141ddd350de329).